# get attachment info with php mime_parser

Tags: php, parsing, email-attachments

I am trying to get the information from an XML file that is being sent as an attachment on an email with php.  I'm using mime_parser.php to parse the email.  Here is the code I'm working with:

```
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

//SET UP EMAIL PARSER CLASS
$mime=new mime_parser_class;
$mime->ignore_syntax_errors = 1;
$parameters=array('Data'=>$email,);

//RESULTS GET ADDED TO $decoded VARIABLE
$mime->Decode($parameters, $decoded);

//---------------------- GET EMAIL HEADER INFO -----------------------//

//get the name and email of the sender
$fromName = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['from:'][0]['name'];
$fromEmail = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['from:'][0]['address'];

//get the name and email of the recipient
$toEmail = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['to:'][0]['address'];
$toName = $decoded[0]['ExtractedAddresses']['to:'][0]['name'];

//get the subject
$subject = $decoded[0]['Headers']['subject:'];

$removeChars = array('<','>');

//get the message id
$messageID = str_replace($removeChars,'',$decoded[0]['Headers']['message-id:']);

//get the reply id
$replyToID = str_replace($removeChars,'',$decoded[0]['Headers']['in-reply-to:']);
//---------------------- END GET EMAIL HEADER INFO -----------------------//

//---------------------- FIND THE BODY -----------------------//
//get the message body
if(substr($decoded[0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Body'])){
    $body = $decoded[0]['Body'];
} elseif(substr($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Body'])) {
    $body = $decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Body'];
} elseif(substr($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Headers']['content-type:'],0,strlen('text/plain')) == 'text/plain' && isset($decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Body'])) {
    $body = $decoded[0]['Parts'][0]['Parts'][0]['Body'];
}
//---------------------- END FIND THE BODY -----------------------//
```

I can't find anything on how to get the attachment info.  A few examples showed it as being part of the header but as far as I can tell it is not.  If anyone has info on where the attachment info is I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this PHP Mime Mail Parser [link](https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/).

Example listed:

```
<?php
require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

$path = 'path/to/mail.txt';
$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$from = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$text = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();    
?>
```